# is it possible to prevent jquery dialog box from showing when the page loads?

Tags: jquery

Hey guys I was not really sure how to word the title to make it short, but my question is when my page loads, it includes a jquery dialog box is supposed to start off closed. It does but when the page first loads, the contents of that box briefly show before disappearing when the page is finished loading. It looks a little awkward so I was wondering if anyone knew of some sort of solution to fix this problem or smooth it over. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a class to the div which sets display:none.

For an app wide solution read about [FOUC here](http://paulirish.com/2009/avoiding-the-fouc-v3/) from Paul Irish

> FOUC is an unwelcome guest to your
>   soirée of intertube funtimes. He comes
>   in and distracts users eyes with
>   things they shouldn't be seeing, and
>   then departs ever so quickly. We don't
>   like him.....

Answer (score 10):

When you call [`.dialog()`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) make sure to pass the [`autoOpen` option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#option-autoOpen) as `false`, like this:

```
$("#myDiv").dialog({
  autoOpen: false
});
```

This prevents the dialog from opening immediately, you open it later by calling the [`open` method](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#method-open):

```
$("#myDiv").dialog("open");
```

---

As [@redsquare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6440/redsquare) points you should have it `style="display: none;"` to start with, whether in-line or in external CSS, so it's not showing before the JavaScript runs, that's a separate issue than `dialog()` displaying it initially, like this:

```
<div id="myDiv" style="display: none;">Stuff</div>
```

Or in CSS:

```
#myDiv { display: none; }
```

The dialog opening will reverse this `none` style.

Comment: Nick, I think he is talking about FOUC

Comment: @redsquare - Ah, yes that might be the case, one moment

Comment: thanks that was what I was talking about Nick, the display none fixed it

Comment: @Scarface - Make sure to accept red's answer for pointing it out :)

Comment: @Nick-Craver, very charitable of you :-)

Answer (score 1):

Set this in your CSS file:

```css
#myDiv { display: none }
```

and

```
$("#myDiv").dialog({
  autoOpen: false
});
```

in your JS.